# Trying to use VBA to open a link in Citrix webpage from Excel

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA, trying to figure out an issue I've got.

I have multiple anchors with the same name on a Citrix web page with multiple tools, the only thing that differs for each tool is the title and href. For example for Putty it has:

```
<div class="iconView">
<a  id="idCitrix.Putty"
href="launcher.aspx?Application=Citrix....
class="iconLink"
title="Putty"
```

The same class and id is present for all other tools on the URL. I can scrape all of the URls with no issues, and I can open the first tool if I just use:

```
For Each l In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") '(0).href
    l.Click
Next l
```

I can't find any way to reference the Putty instance though, tools are regularly added here so going by index number isn't an option.
How can I reliably reference and open the putty link above? Is there any options that would allow me to use "title" or a subset of "href" to do this?

Comment: try `ie.Document.getElementById("idCitrix.Putty").Click`

Comment: This works, thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jsotola, this works instead of using the for loop:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("idCitrix.Putty").Click
```